# Swift crash when unwrapping UILabel in UITableView with custom cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uilabel, option-type

I have a Table Bar where i have 3 separate MVC. The first MVC is a `UITableView` where i can search for a location and it will display 10 day forecast. The second MVC also a `UITableView` stores my favourite locations. I can tap on the location and it will bring me another `UITableView` that displays the 10 day forecast just like the first tab bar. However i get an **"Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"** I'm using a custom prototype cell just like the first tab bar view and it works great there. [image]

The code for my first tab bar mvc looks like:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "WeatherDataCell", for: indexPath)

let weatherCell = timeSeries[indexPath.row]
if let wc = cell as? WeatherTableViewCell {
    wc.timeSeries = weatherCell
}

return cell
}
```

The custom prototype cell looks something like:

```
class WeatherTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var WeatherImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var WeatherTimeLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var WeatherTemperatureLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var WeatherWindLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var WeatherPrecipitationLabel: UILabel!

    var timeSeries : TimeSeries? {
        didSet {
            updateUI()
        }
    }

    func updateUI() {
        for parameters in timeSeries!.parameters {
        if parameters.name == "t" {
            let temperature = parameters.values[0]
            WeatherTemperatureLabel.text? = "\(temperature) °C" // <- works for the first MVC but crashes on the second MVC even though i can print out the temperature
        }
    }
}
```

The func in the seconds MVC basically looks the same as the first one so i don't understand why its crashing, it should have data.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "DetailedWeatherCell", for: indexPath) as! WeatherTableViewCell

let weatherCell = timeSeries[indexPath.row]        
let wc = cell
wc.timeSeries = weatherCell

return cell

}
```

added additional code for clarity (my FavoriteDetailedTableViewController class):

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.tableView.register(WeatherTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "DetailedWeatherCell")
}
```

Comment: You're force unwrapping this: `for parameters in timeSeries!.parameters`. There's probably a nil value in there that blows up when there's a `timeseries` that's expected, but isn't there. You should use an `if let` or `guard let` for unwrapping `timeseries`

Comment: Check if `WeatherTemperatureLabel ` is linked in storyboard or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you forgot to change identifier of prototype cell in FavoritedDetailedTableViewController. In this TableViewController change it to

[image]

and it should work.

Second you maybe forgot to set your cell class here

[image]

Also delete this line from viewDidLoad

```
self.tableView.register(WeatherTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "DetailedWeatherCell")
```

Comment: Did u mean         self.tableView.register(WeatherTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "DetailedWeatherCell")

Comment: If the cells are designed in IB as prototype cells you **must not** register the cells.

Comment: @Robert Dresler I did as you said but i got another crash now:  "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier WeatherDataCell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'"

Comment: @xxFlashxx ok, let code as it was and try just change reuse identifier in storyboard and delete this one line where you register cell as I described in edited answer

Comment: @RobertDresler changed and deleted the line. Same crash with unable to dequeue a cell...

Comment: @xxFlashxx did you change it in both view controllers or just in one?

Comment: @RobertDresler both

Comment: @xxFlashxx and that's the problem, for Weather forecast set identifier as WeatherDataCell and for FavoritedDetailedTableViewController set identifier as DetailedWeatherCell

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183517/discussion-between-robert-dresler-and-xxflashxx).

Answer (score 1):

- 2 Viewcontrollers can not reuse the same prototype cell which had been created by one of two viewcontrollers
- WeatherTableViewCell can't have 2 layouts in mvc1, mvc2
  =>  You have to create your customer cell in xib file and register a cell for UITableViewCell reuse.